# Python tempfile [Errno 66] Directory not empty

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I need to process some file generated from db objects and after required process need to delete that directory with files.I have decided to use python templefile package. I have give it a try but stuck on `Direcotry not Empty [ Error 66 ].`

In **views.py**

```
def writeFiles(request, name):
    tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    instance = request.user.instances.get(name=name)
    print(instance)
    print(instance.name)
    code = instance.serverFile
    jsonFile = instance.jsonPackageFile
    docker = """
    FROM node
    # Create app directory
    RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
    WORKDIR /usr/src/ap

    # Install app dependencies
    COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
    RUN npm install

    # Bundle app source
    COPY . /usr/src/app

    EXPOSE 8080
    CMD [ "node", "server" ]"""
    # Ensure the file is read/write by the creator only
    saved_umask = os.umask(0o077)
    server = 'server.js'
    json = 'package.json'
    path = os.path.join(tmpdir)
    print(path)
    try:
        with open(path + '/dockerfile', "w") as dockerfile:
            dockerfile.write(docker)
        with open(path + '/server.js', "w") as server:
            server.write(code)
        with open(path + 'package.json', "w") as json:
            json.write(jsonFile)
        print(os.path.join(tmpdir, json))
    except IOError as e:
        print('IOError:', e)
    else:
        os.remove(path)
    finally:
        os.umask(saved_umask)
        os.rmdir(tmpdir)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll just note that `path = os.path.join(tmpdir)` makes `path` equal to `tmpdir`. That said, when a directory is not empty, neither `os.remove` or `os.rmdir` will work.

Those are operating system calls, which don't recurse to files contained in the directory.

So just use

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree(tmpdir)
```